# LSTM to multivariate sequence classification

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, sequence

How can I train multivariate to multiclass sequence using LSTM in keras?

I have 50000 sequences, each in the length of 100 timepoints.
At every time point, I have 3 features (So the width is 3).

I have 4 classes and I want to bulid a classifier to determine class for sequence.
What is the best way to do so?

I saw many guides for univariate sequence classification but none for multivariate, and I don't know how to apply this on the multivariate case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Since you are using **LSTMs for classification** using the
  **multivariate time series** data, you need to model your time-series data into a **supervised learning problem** and specify the previous
  time steps you need to look before by specifying the time-lag count
- You need to look into the [to_supervised](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/) function and specify the number of outputs your model has. In your case, it is 4.
- Split your train and test set from the whole set of data. A 70:30 ratio for the train, test would be a good start.
- Also, note that you need to scale your values using the
  `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` function.
- You need to reshape your train and test values into (batch_size/sample_size, time_steps, feature_size) as an LSTM Layer in Keras expects your data to be fed in a 3D array format.
- For eg: Your training shape would be `train.shape = (batch_size, 100, 3)`

And for the model building in Keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(number_of_hidden_units, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps = 100, n_features = 3))) 
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax')) #since number of output classes is 4
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), no_of_epochs, batch_size)
```

Note that I have just given a rough outline of the model building and left out the hyperparameters at your convenience. You can either stack more LSTM layers onto the model or tune the number of hidden_layers in the model Refer [Multi-Class Classification](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/) for more details on it.

Comment: loss='categorical_crossentropy' is more fitting here.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, this article explains some generalized methods for clustering using DTW on multivariate data. Especially useful for IOT data

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-020-00727-3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).